# Spring Integration - Filter - Send messages to a different end point

Tags: filter, spring-integration, channel

My input is a csv file as given below:

```
USER_ID, USER_NAME, FREQUENCY, FREQUENCY_DETAIL
A123, AAA, ANNUALLY, 1-JUN
B123, BBB, INVALID_FREQUENCY, 21-JUN
C123, CCC, ANNUALLY, APR
D123, DDD, WEEKLY, 1-DEC
```

Validations:

```
USER_ID -> alphanumeric
USERNAME -> alphabets only
FREQUENCY -> must be one of DAILY, WEEKLY, MONTHLY , ANNUALLY
FREQUENCY DETAIL -> Pattern \\d{1,2}-\\w{3}
```

My Bean is as follows:

```
class UserBean {
    String userID;
    String userName;
    String frequency;
    String frequencyDetail;

    String status = "SUCCESS"; //Code generated. If any of the above fields is not valid, set as "ERROR, <field that failed>". E.g.: ERROR, FREQUENCY_DETAIL
}
```

My flow is as follows:

1. Read csv file from folder
2. Convert to UserBean (using openCsv)
3. If the status of any of the beans contains "ERROR", write to a separate channel called "errorSummaryReportChannel".

This channels writes userID + status to a file.

***4. For all beans (with status = "SUCCESS" or status = "ERROR"), convert to JSON and log output.***

***WHERE I NEED HELP:***

Step 3

If the userBean has status = "ERROR", write to  "errorSummaryReportChannel".
For all status, proceed with normal flow.

I think an output channel & discard channel must be added, but could not find any example.

My code:

```
@Configuration
public class CreateUserConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow createUser() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(INPUT_DIR)))
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("errorChannel", "exceptionChannel", true))
                .transform(csvToUserBeanTransformer, "convertCsvToUserBean")
                .split(userBeanSplitter, "splitUserBeans")
                .wireTap(flow -> flow.<PrimeAOBean>filter(primeAOBean -> primeAOBean.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS"), errorFlow -> errorFlow.discardChannel("errorSummaryReportGenerationChannel")))
                .transform(userBeanToJSONTransformer, "convertUserBeanToJSON")
                .handle(Files.outboundAdapter(new File(OUTPUT_SUCCESS_DIRECTORY)))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow logErrorSummary() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("errorSummaryReportGenerationChannel")
                .handle((p,h) -> {
                    return ((UserBean)(p)).getUserID() + "\t" + ((UserBean)(p)).getStatus();
                })
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .handle(Files.outboundAdapter(new File(OUTPUT_FAILED_REPORT_FILE_NAME)))
                .get();
    }

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow logError() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("exceptionChannel")
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression("errorFileName", "payload.failedMessage.headers.fileName"))
            .transform(Transformers.toJson())
            .handle(Files.outboundAdapter(new File(generateOutputDirectory(OUTPUT_FAILED_DIRECTORY))))
            .get();
}

}
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: @Artem Bilan, can you please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

The *output channel* for `filter` (or any other endpoint) in the flow is the one created automatically before the endpoint in the flow. So, in your case it is like this:

```
 .filter()
 .transform()
```

Whenever message has passed the filter, it is sent into that transformer. We can treat it as a `SUCCESS` process.

Now let's write a filter function first of all to make those message to flow properly!

There is a method like this for you:

```
/**
 * Populate a {@link MessageFilter} with {@link MethodInvokingSelector}
 * for the provided {@link GenericSelector}.
 * Typically used with a Java 8 Lambda expression:
 * <pre class="code">
 * {@code
 *  .filter("World"::equals)
 * }
 * </pre>
 * Use {@link #filter(Class, GenericSelector)} if you need to access the entire
 * message.
 * @param genericSelector the {@link GenericSelector} to use.
 * @param <P> the source payload type.
 * @return the current {@link IntegrationFlowDefinition}.
 */
public <P> B filter(GenericSelector<P> genericSelector) {
```

So, our task is to implement that `GenericSelector` for your `UserBean`:

```
 .<UserBean>filter(userBean -> userBean.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS"))
```

To send all other (`ERROR`) message to the discard channel (`errorSummaryReportGenerationChannel`), we need to add that `discardChannel` option into the filter somehow. And for this purpose there is an overloaded `filter()` method in Java DSL:

```
.<UserBean>filter(userBean -> userBean.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS"),
               endpoint -> endpoint.discardChannel("errorSummaryReportGenerationChannel"))
```

See their JavaDocs for more information.

Comment: Thankyou Artem. I have modified the requirement a bit and updated the question.


Step 3: If the status = "ERROR", write to a separate channel "errorSummaryReportGenerationChannel".
Step 4: For all status (SUCCESS | ERROR), allow normal flow to proceed and log the response.

I need to see the stack trace of exception being thrown in case of ERROR. So step 3 should not be a filter, instead it should be an extra step.

Comment: do you think doing the below will help?

wireTap(flow -> flow.<PrimeAOBean>filter(primeAOBean -> primeAOBean.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS"), errorFlow -> errorFlow.discardChannel("errorSummaryReportGenerationChannel")))

Comment: Yeah... That's not good. You fully changes requirements and that really requires a different answer...

Comment: So, yeah... That is really a `wireTap()` with the filter, but already based on the *opposite* assumption: if `ERROR`, send to `errorSummaryReportGenerationChannel`, otherwise ignore. And you are right: both `SUCCESS` and `ERROR` are going to be sent downstream.

Comment: Looks like you are linking to itself, @Deepboy. Please, consider to fix your comment.

Comment: folow up question posted on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120142/spring-integration-custom-errorchannel-only-first-exception-gets-logged/58120926#58120926