# Spring Integration - custom errorChannel - only first exception gets logged

Tags: exception, error-handling, spring-integration, customization

This is a follow up to the previous question (requirements given in original question).

[Spring Integration - Filter - Send messages to a different end point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58103341/spring-integration-filter-send-messages-to-a-different-end-point)

**My issue** is that if there is more than one error in the input file, only the first error is getting logged. The subsequent errors are not getting logged.

**Modified code:**

```
@Configuration
public class CreateUserConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow createUser() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(INPUT_DIR)))
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("errorChannel", "exceptionChannel", true))
                .transform(csvToUserBeanTransformer, "convertCsvToUserBean")
                .split(userBeanSplitter, "splitUserBeans")
                .wireTap(flow -> flow.<UserBean>filter(userBean -> !userBean.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS")).channel("errorSummaryReportGenerationChannel"))
                .transform(userBeanToJSONTransformer, "convertUserBeanToJSON")
                .handle(Files.outboundAdapter(new File(OUTPUT_SUCCESS_DIRECTORY)))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow logErrorSummary() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("errorSummaryReportGenerationChannel")
                .handle((p,h) -> {
                    return ((UserBean)(p)).getUserID() + "\t" + ((UserBean)(p)).getStatus();
                })
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .handle(Files.outboundAdapter(new File(OUTPUT_FAILED_REPORT_FILE_NAME)))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow logError() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("exceptionChannel")
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression("errorFileName", "payload.failedMessage.headers.fileName"))
                .wireTap(flow -> flow.handle(msg -> System.out.println("Received on exceptionChannel " + msg.getHeaders().get("errorFileName"))))
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .handle(Files.outboundAdapter(new File(generateOutputDirectory(OUTPUT_FAILED_DIRECTORY))).autoCreateDirectory(true).fileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.APPEND).fileNameExpression("getHeaders().get(\"errorFileName\")+'.json'"))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean(name = "exceptionChannel")
    MessageChannel exceptionChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.executor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor()).get();
    }

    @Bean(name="errorSummaryReportGenerationChannel")
    MessageChannel errorSummaryReportGenerationChannel() {
        return DirectChannel();
    }
}
```

**WHAT I EXPECT:**

In errorSummaryReport -

```
B123  ERROR, FREQUENCY
C123  FREQUENCY_DETAIL
```

In OUTPUT_FAILED_DIRECTORY -

```
B123.json -> stacktrace of error
C123.json -> stacktrace of error
```

**WHAT I SEE: (C123 information is missing)**

In errorSummaryReport -

```
B123  ERROR, FREQUENCY
```

In OUTPUT_FAILED_DIRECTORY -

```
B123.json -> stacktrace of error
```

Comment: @Artem Bilan, Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem pops up from the `.split(userBeanSplitter, "splitUserBeans")`.

I would say it is fully similar to what we do in plain Java with a `for` loop.
So, if method in the loop throws an exception, you indeed go away from the loop and the next item is not going to be processed any more.

To fix your problem you need to add a `.channel(c -> c.executor(myExecutor()))` to process splitted items in parallel and have a error handling in the separate thread. This way the loop in the splitter is not going to be affected.

Comment: Or, if you want to process them sequentially, you could add a `.gateway(...)` after the splitter and use its error channel for each split.